can I set httpOnly and Max_Age on HttpHeaders Set Cookie?
I'm trying to add httpOnly on my Set_Cookie but I can't find anything about it on the docs.
This is what I tried
@PostMapping("/login")
    ResponseEntity<UserDto> login(@RequestBody UserDto userDto){
        UserDto userDtoResponse = userService.convertToDto(userService.login(userDto.email(), userDto.password()));
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, "token="+userDtoResponse.jwtToken());
        System.out.println(httpHeaders);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).headers(httpHeaders).body(userDtoResponse.noPassword());


    }

But the cookie gets intantly deleted once I update my frontend page, so needed to set Max_Age and it also doesn't apply httpOnly.
@Edit
For anyone who has the same question as me: All you gotta do is put a ; after the value and set the properties there, like:
httpHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, "token="+userDtoResponse.jwtToken()+";Max-Age:"+value+";HttpOnly");

